# Fortran program unable to read anything past first line in file

Tags: loops, fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to read line by line a list of files in a different directory. This list is stored in the file unit 10. It successfully reads in the first entry, but not any of the following

```
do plvl_count = 0, plvls
  do line_num = 0, numlines
    read(10,*) filename
    fullpath = trim(out_dir) // '/' // trim(filename)
    call read_binary(trim(fullpath),avg_temp_flat)
    avg_temp = reshape(avg_temp_flat,(/numlats,numlons/))
    if (line_num == 0) then
      avg_out(:,:,plvl_count) = avg_temp
    else
      avg_out(:,:,plvl_count) = avg_out(:,:,plvl_count) + avg_temp
    endif
  end do
end do
```

the error I receive is

```
forrtl: No such file or directory
forrtl: severe (29): file not found, unit 10
```

Above this loop, I pull in several lines of metadata just fine. It's only when I'm in the loop, cycling through files do I encounter errors. The read_binary subroutine has been heavily tested and is not the source of the error. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You don't show the `open` of unit `10`, or the file's contents, but it seems the problem is reading that file, not a file derived from its contents.

Comment: could it be `read_binary` tries to open using unit 10?

Comment: I didn't realize the unit for read_binary was also 10 (that code was provided for me). Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Some I/O (mostly the O part) can be used to say what you want to open. EXISTANCE or something like that can be used to see if there is a file, and some echoing of that could happen.